# C Programming - analyzing prose in a string?

Tags: c

If given the following char prose:

> "Hope is the thing with feathers
>   That perches in the soul
>   And sings the tune without the words
>   And never stops at all”

How do I count the length of the string and number of spaces?  Here is what I have thus far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int count(char *string);
int main(void){
    char prose[ ] =
        "Hope is the thing with white feathers\n"
        "That perches in the soul.\n"
        "And sings the tne without the words\n"
        "And never stops at all.";
    printf("count of word : %d\n", count(&prose[0]));
    return 0;
}
char *NextWordTop(char *string){
    static char *p = NULL;
    char *ret;
    if(string)
        p = string;
    else if(!p)
        return NULL;
    while(isspace(*p))++p;
    if(*p){
        ret = p;
        while(!isspace(*p))++p;
    } else
        ret = p = NULL;
    return ret;
}
int count(char *str){
    int c = 0;
    char *p;
    for(p=NextWordTop(str); p ; p=NextWordTop(NULL))
        ++c;
    return c;
}
```

Comment: are you trying to count the number of words?  or the number of characters?

Comment: I think you're very much complicating what needs to be done with `NextWordTop` and `count`.

Comment: You should get rid of the static variable in NextWordTop() and simply call `p = NextWordTop(p)` in the `for` loop reinitialization expression.

Comment: Maybe on linux, how about `fgrep -o ' ' dat | wc -l` for counting spaces.

Comment: @gongzhitaao: that would be `system("fgrep..(etc.)");` then, since the OP asked for C.

Comment: Funny enough, this code returns (at least!) one character less than in the assignment prose. A more serious note: is a newline not a kind of space?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void){
    char prose[ ] =
        "Hope is the thing with white feathers\n"
        "That perches in the soul.\n"
        "And sings the tne without the words\n"
        "And never stops at all.";
    int len, spc;
    char *p = prose;
    for(len=spc=0;*p;++p){
        ++len;
        if(isspace(*p))//if(' ' == *p)
            ++spc;
    }
    printf("length : %d\t spaces : %d\n", len, spc);
    //length : 123     spaces : 23
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So much simpler! Thanks for timely response!